# Absolute convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Determine if absolutely  convergent or not; Justify.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^2 3^{1-n} x^n \text{ s.t }|x|<3$$

if we take the abs value of $(-1)^n$ we are left with $n^{2} 3^{1-n} x^{n}$ now it become clear that it is abs convergent but how to make the argument let $r= \frac {x^{n}}{3^{n}}$ since $|x|<3 $ $\rightarrow$ $r<1$ can i just write $\frac {n^{2}}{r^{n}}$? if so can i then use the ratio test on this new argument to show that its less then 1 and conclude that its absolutely convergent?

Comment: You can apply the Ratio Test with things as they are, but might be more comfortable rewriting the $n$-th term as $(3)(-1)^n \frac{n^2}{3^n}x^n$,

Comment: Hmm, ok but is what i did legitimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's best to simply begin with the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)^2}{3^{(n+1)-1}}\frac{3^{n-1}}{n^2}x\right|=\left|\frac{x}{3}\right|$$

This shows absolute convergence for $-3<x<3$.